# Abort job on failed fragements yt-dlp

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I've written a downloader in python 3.9.1 that utilizes yt-dlp, using this format:

```
outTmpl = "{}"
rows = c.fetchall()
ydl_opts = dict()
for row in rows:
    ydl_opts = {
    'verbose': True,
    'outtmpl': outTmpl.format(row[1]),
    'abort-on-unavailable-fragment': True,
    }
    with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([row[0]])
```

However some downloads skip fragments (due to timeouts or whatever), leaving me with something that is cut short.

Any idea what i need to put in the ydl_opts? I thought `'abort-on-unavailable-fragment': True` would suffice, but the download carries on and processes the file with ffmpeg.

Any idea how i fix this please and if it starts failing to download segments, just abort the job and remove any files its created? Maybe the option i'm calling is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is named `skip_unavailable_fragments`. See the [docstring of FragmentFD](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/blob/d8cf8d97a8dbc9602556de474af133b5ab0e0a29/yt_dlp/downloader/fragment.py#L40-L52)

> if it starts failing to download segments, just abort the job and remove any files its created?

There is no functionality in yt-dlp to automatically remove the temporary files. You will have to catch the error and do it yourself

Comment: Will that option abort the job (not passing onto ffmpeg?). 

I can handle the temp files that get created like you say with error handling. Its just when it processes the file and looks like everything has worked.

Comment: Thanks @pukkandan , I tried that and it didn't seem to make any difference, it still skips the fragments, to 100% leaving a file that is half the size/length it should be.

From the download options page of github, this option describes exactly what i'm trying to achieve:

`--abort-on-unavailable-fragment      
Abort downloading when some fragment is not available`

Comment: I guess i wasn't using the option correctly - setting skip_unavailable_fragments to false, does what i require.

Thanks for your help.